# How to assign an output of a stored procedure that is nested in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has a nested stored procedure that is executed when the parent stored procedure is executed.

Can the output of the nested stored procedure be assigned to a `@variable` and the output in a select statement?

`EXEC   @bat_key = [dbo].[client_icc_set_batch]` - I can see the output here but would also like to include the output in a `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT  'return_key' = @bat_key
```

Comment: The answer is probably, but you don't provide enough information to show you how. What sort of output are you using?

Comment: Have you read MSDN documentation???  That's probably the first place to check before asking a question here.

Comment: @Bargo - there are people here who really want to help... we just need you to put some more detail into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it like this:

```
DECLARE @bat_key INT

CREATE TABLE #tmp (bat_key INT)

INSERT #tmp
EXEC [dbo].[client_icc_set_batch];

SET @bat_key = (
        SELECT TOP 1 bat_key
        FROM #tmp
        order by bat_key DESC
        );

SELECT 'return_key' + '=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @bat_key)

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: How does assigning a table to a variable work? `SET @bat_key = (SELECT * FROM #tmp);`

Comment: Because you can't set a variable by executing stored procedure. You can however select into a table using a stored procedure so you then select your variable out of the table. It isn't the prettiest but it does work. I have to do this sort of thing often because I work pulling out of several databases at once. This works.

Comment: Sure but if you are selecting from a table you should ensure you select 1 column and 1 row i.e. `SELECT top 1 @bat_key = bat_key FROM #tmp order by bat_key` so that its clear what is happening rather than relying on some default behaviour of SQL Server.

Comment: I was assuming that this would only be happening one at a time for each key.

Comment: As I said, best to make it clear exactly what is happening, especially when you are passing on this knowledge to a newbie. It only takes one change in how the SP works later for it all to break if you rely on certain behaviour. I see you have updated your question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. This will save a lot of time.